# value of setState passed to function until second onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'm looking to implement those buttons to run same function but different values of `query`, now it's working but the parameter is not passed to the `searchfunc` function:

```
  searchfunc = () => {

  const { query } = this.state;
  let url = "http://url/api/?q=" + query
  Keyboard.dismiss()

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        data: responseJson.results,
      });
    })
};
```

My code looks like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => {
    this.setState({query: 'donut'});
    this.searchfunc();          }}
>
<Text>Donuts</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

On the second onPress I got the donuts results I was expecting. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setState` [method offers a callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that is fired after the state modification (ie `{query:'donut'}`) has been applied.

You can make use of this callback to resolve your issue, by making the following adjustment:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => { 
    this.setState({query: 'donut'}, () => this.searchfunc());
}}>
    <Text>Donuts</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This will cause `this.searchfunc()` to be called after the `this.setState({query:'donut'} ..` state change has taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should pass the query as the function parameter than keeping it in the state. Since `setState` works asynchronously and does a batch update. So it might happen that state for the query is not the latest while making the api call.